# How Do I Update Windows 10 IoT to the latest version? I'm stuck on 17763.107 and I want 17763.503

Tags: windows-iot-core

How Do I Update Windows 10 IoT to the latest version? I'm stuck on 17763.107 and I want 17763.503

I have all ports open , including port 443 and I cannot get it to Update using Windows Update.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: This would be using windows update, as described above. I've already tried this, Moab, but thanks.

Comment: No its not windows update.

Comment: Here's a good solution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d83dd1a-1a79-48f3-940b-cf4ed1b9685f/windows-update-issue-with-windows-10-iot-build-17763107-on-rpi3?forum=WindowsIoT